# Outlook Print handling

Tags: vba, printing, outlook, event-handling

I'm trying to solve a problem with saving logs of printed mails. 
Unfortunately there is no event as in word or excel like "BeforePrint" or "AfterPrint". Can someone support me by an idea, how can i catch moment of printing? There is only PrintOut method, can I handle it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three approaches:

1. Replace all print buttons and shortcuts with a call to your code that logs and prints
2. Print to PDFs to queue folder and build something that picks up these, prints and logs
3. Subclass the print dialog. This is the very complex alternative, and I'm not sure if it is still possible.

Comment: Cheers mate,I go for 1st idea, i will be back and post a report how i've done it.

Comment: Oh didn't mention that i need it working on 2007,2010 and 2016 outlook. Is it possible to make it for all of them at once or i have to make it separately for each of versions?